# How to use BSON with Refit client

Tags: refit

I am trying to use a [Refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit) client against a method in a ASP.NET 6 controller that returns Bson. The method looks like this:

```
[Produces("application/bson", Type=typeof(MyDto))]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetBinaryDataAsBson(Guid id)
```

In the project there is a class BsonMediaTypeFormatter that use Newtonsoft BsonDataWriter to write BSON.

```
public override Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context)
        {
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var bsonWriter = new BsonDataWriter(ms) { CloseOutput = false })
                {
                    var jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(_jsonSerializerSettings);
                    jsonSerializer.Serialize(bsonWriter, context.Object);
                    bsonWriter.Flush();
                }

                return response.Body.WriteAsync(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
            }
        }
```

When I try the client returns null for Content.
It works if I change application/bson to json in the Produces attribute.

Does anyone know how make Refit work with BSON?

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick look at Refit and it has a `IHttpContentSerializer` that you can add to the `RefitSettings` to control how it (de)serializes.  So just write a concrete class that implements your desired serialization format.